# Can I map an external drive plugged on a Linux netbook into a Windows PC over the internet?

Tags: networking, server, lubuntu, samba

I have a netbook running Lubuntu 16.04 with two External HDD serving as a Home Server. I already mapped it into my Windows computers over my home network but I would like to map it over the internet in a different machine on my office. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  An easy method to map the device under samba.  The device being internal or external doesn't make any difference.  The criterion is that you can access the drive on your Linux box for sharing.

**An example of Samba configuration is (/etc/samba/smb.conf):**

```
[SharedDrive]
        comment = Shared External Drive
        path = /media/myexternaldrive
        writeable = yes
        browseable = yes
        valid users = user1, user2
```

Make sure the external drive is available at boot time when the samba configuration will start.

**An fstab entry is (/etc/fstab):**

```
UUID="60292932-ae7d-4676-8f0f-7c319cb66fee" /media/myexternaldrive  ext4  defaults 0 0
```

The `path` entry `smb.conf` file is the mounted point of your external drive.  The valid users are usernames on the linux machine.  You would use `sudo smbpasswd [username] -a` to add the user to the samba permissions list.

The `/etc/fstab` entry is the `UUID` of the external drive and the `mount point`.

**From Windows browse or map the drive:**

There are many ways of adding file shares to Windows.  You can do this simply by opening up your Windows file browserand putting the IP address or hostname of the Ubuntu machine, in this format: `\\192.168.1.100\`. This will list all your shared devices from the Ubuntu machine.  Double click on the share you want and answer the username and password you have provided in the configurations above.

You can also right click on the shared resource and click `map network drive` to assign a drive letter to the device.

**Making your Ubuntu visible from outside your local network**

You will have to configure your router to forward the port for your Samba server to your Ubuntu computer.  The default ports are `TCP ports 139 and 445`.  The UDP defaults are `UDP ports 137 and 138`.

The port forwarding in most routers will be found under the Security group.  On a Linksys router (Linksys Smart Wi-Fi), you can get to it by:

```
Click Security -> Apps and Gaming -> Port Forwarding
```

You will find some similar wordings in most Routers.  You might have to look up port forwarding in your Router's manual.

You can find the IP address of your ubuntu computer either by browsing your router's configuration or by running this on the commandline:

```
hostname -I
```

Comment: Uh, but won't the OP need to setup port forwarding and stuff since he wants to do this over WAN?

Comment: Yes.  I'll add the formated the steps in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks a lot a lot for your answer. I already have the external drive mapped and running over my home network (WAN) with Samba and works fine. I´ll try to access the router and do the port forward thing and see how it goes. Does I have to use a service like no-ip for Dynamic DNS? I am such a noob for those things and it´s  hard to configure everything all by myself. tks for the help!

Comment: I've try to do it, but I could not complete the task as my router did not enable the "apply" button so it can´t add port forwarding... I´ve been looking for information but nobody seems to have the same problem as I... really don´t know what to do now... http://prntscr.com/gel11l

Comment: The `Add/Apply` button is disabled because you have not enabled the rules.  Looking at your screen there are some fields that will have to be populated before you can apply the settings.  You'll have to give your rule a name by putting something in the **Name** field.  You'll also have to specify the **IP Address** and **port number** that you want to apply.  You place arrows to the last settings that you would have to specify.  You can't apply an `End Port` without a  `Start Port`.  You can't `Add/Apply` settings that you haven't specified.

Comment: By the way, if you see any value or merit in my answer, consider an upvote or accepting the answer.  I wouldn't expect for the answer to be accepted while you still have questions on how to apply the steps.

Comment: tks James, I do have upvoted it... in fact even if I populate the list with the correct port and IP address and so on it not enable the buttons I marked on... I willl continue to try and read the manual, I even wrote an email to the router tech support... tks again!

Comment: Two things:  **(1)** Will you provide an image of the populated fields.  I may be able to identify what is going wrong.  You may not be able to **Add/Apply** conflicting entries.  **(2)** Will you provide the make and manufacturer of your router?

Comment: Yes, of course! here it is http://prntscr.com/geo8ha and the router is a D-Link DMG-6661

Comment: I'm searching for the manual on their site.  So far it appears they don't have any support references to that particular model.  This is the page I'm seeing: [D-Link's Supported Products](http://support.dlink.com/list.aspx?type=1&model=dmg)].  They don't have any DMG series in the listing.  It goes from **DMF** to **DMP**.  It doesn't show anything between those two codes.  The screen you want to go into, by the way, as mentioned in the answer, is the **Security** settings.  You shouldn't have to create a **Virtual Server** to configure port forwarding.

Comment: I'm still trying to find a manual so that I can give you the exact steps.

Comment: Of course, the Virtual Server while I'm thinking it might be an optional method, it might be a required method for your particular router, if the security settings, where the feature normally is located, doesn't have this configuration option.

Comment: The program is probably having a problem with the non-alpha numeric characters in your name field.  Try something simple like **Name1** or **Samba** for the name.  When you have a workable combination, the `Add/Apply` button will become clickable.  It's not going to allow you to save something that won't work.  Let me know how you make out when you fix the name field.

Comment: [Virtual Server does seem to be the primary method of port forwarding for this particular router.](https://portforward.com/d-link/dmg-6661/)

Comment: @drkokandy Thanks for the confirmation.  Now as with the previous comment, the user needs to check what he has put in the fields.  As with your link, he should remove the none alpha-numeric characters from the name field.  Using `Name1` should work.

Comment: It seems that does not matter what I put on the fields (or leave it blank) I cannot configure it. But I managed to now access my server in my windows machine on a web browser offiste. I am able to login to a SSH terminal and a Webmin server I previously installed on the server. Tks a lot for the tips

Comment: Just an update, I discover my ISP blocks the most common port (21, 22, 139, 445, and so on...) so that´s why I could not manage to change it, even if I tried hard. I´ll have to to some workaround on this subject.

Comment: Blocking a port shouldn't have anything to do with configuring your Router.  You should be able to input the desired specs, whether they work or not.  After putting in the desired specs, you can test them and change them to a port that isn't blocked.    I believe your first and main problem is to fix your Router so that you can enter the desired information.  Then work on specifying a port that isn't blocked.  The router doesn't know which port is blocked, you might not be sure which ports are blocked also.  So you should be able to at least enter a port in the configuration to test it.